# SpringBoot Application Exiting Time

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, time, ide, exit

Every single time when i'm exiting my program, I have to wait a minute to shutdown the application. (I am currently using Spring Initalizr to get project skeleton & Spring's extra classes.)
[image]
So, the project is total empty except the output you see and folders (and json files in resources). This is the xml.pom file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>json-processing</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-json-processing</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-json-processing</name>
    <description>Seeding data from Json files.</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have controller class:
[image]

I couldn't find any solution to this problem in my IDE (IntelliJ Ultimate).

I will be glad to get helped! : )

Comment: Get the thread dumps using `jstack` to see what your app is doing on shutdown. Could be some antivirus/firewall issue.

Comment: Please add code as code not as images. That being said, you are writing your code in a `CommandLineRunner` which is invoked during startup of the application, so you are basically (temporarily) delaying startup of your application. Which after typing exit, will continue, to later exit. You also use JPA which depending on your database might be slow to startup, if it creates of validates the schema it might be slow. So you are not just doing this, there is a whole lot more in your application that *might* interfere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is related to `spring-data-jpa` . If you initialize `spring-data-jpa`, it keeps alive the application for at least 60 seconds before shutdown hook is invoked. I did not find the reason.

One workaround is shutdown the application manually.

```
@Autowired
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Override
public void run(String... args){
    applicationContext.close();
}
```